# Can google sign be used just to log in?

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm going to implement Google Sign in my app to let the users log in with their google account. This app doesn't allow registration, as the users are created in a web portal.

The web also have google sign, except that it does uses it for registration.

So, what I want is to only use this in the android app to log users who has already registered at the portal. Is that possible?

I'm following [the android docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), which says I need to configure a Google Api console project, do I need two (one for the android app and the other for the web), or it can be managed with just one? Also, I'm wondering the same question having two apps (android and iOS).

I'm trying to understand the logic of the process. Google docs explain how to do it, but I wanted to know a little more about what's happening.

Comment: uhm... why not also register them with the app? because not doing so, makes the app depend on the web portal registration, which appears to be a questionable process flow.

Comment: one console project can be represented by multiple keys (ios/android/web/etc). I agree with martin btw. But yes you can do what you want. Just depends on how you process the google token

Comment: Yes @MartinZeitler it's not  a good process flow normally but this is a private app for company workers. It's not like normal users are going to registers everyday, so they prefer to register with the portal and use that user whenever they use the app.

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela you could limit the registration to the scope of a GSuite domain - or by validating access permissions with an existing user directory, in order to support off-domain email addresses. eg. https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for the answer. So just one project for all platforms? Ok. You'll think it was a little easy but that was really my question along with the login part, so if you to answer making it up a little bit (I appreciate it if you elaborate a little to help me understand this exchange between the platforms and the console project) I'll give you the answer :)

Comment: @MartinZeitler that's also a good tip, appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly then you need to implement the google authentication process in your application that can be used in all the platforms (Web, iOS, Android).

Google has a platform Firebase Authentication solely for this purpose.
https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/

Here you create a project in the firebase console and then use it for all the 3 platforms.

You can go through the google documentation, it is easy to understand and use.

Or you can go through this link to understand how to implement it on Android.
https://medium.com/@valokafor/working-with-firebase-authentication-8f7dcb016e84

Comment: As Tim says, it could be an option but I'm using google sign in for this project. Thanks anyway for your info :)